# Let the order of $a$ and $b$ be different. Is $\left<b\right>a\cap\left<b\right> = \emptyset$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let the order of $a$ and $b$ be different. Is $\left<b\right>a\cap\left<b\right> = \emptyset$?

I'm not sure whether this is true, but after working out some examples I think it is. In case the notation isn't standard: if $a, b \in G$ for some group G, then $\left<b\right>a$ means the subset $\{ha \mid h \in \left<b\right> \}$.

My attempt at a proof is as follows: let $x \in \left<b\right>a \cap \left<b\right>$, then $x = b^\alpha = b^\beta a$, so $a = b^{\alpha - \beta}$. I think this is not possible, but I'm not sure how to prove this. Any help is appreciated, but I prefer hints to the answer straight out.

Comment: Note the intersection of two subgroups of some larger group always contains the identity element so will never be empty.

Comment: FYI, you can use \langle and \rangle for $\langle$ and $\rangle$.

Comment: It doesn't look like $\langle b\rangle a$ always is a subgroup though.

Comment: @Mankind I meant to say $\langle b \rangle$ is a subgroup, and $\langle b \rangle a $ is a subset of G (called the right coset).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about in the cyclic group $C_8$, you take $b$ to have order $4$, and $a = b^2$. Then $a$ has order $2$, so the orders of $a$ and $b$ are different.

However, $\langle b\rangle a$ contains the element $b^3$, and so does $\langle b\rangle$, and thus the two sets are not disjoint.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. Just out of curiosity, does the statement hold for order(a) = 2 and order(b) = 5 (or maybe in general when the orders are coprime)?  I wanted to prove this to prove a specific result in which order(a)  = 2 and order(b)  = 5 (I want to prove that any group of order 10 is either isomorphic to $Z_10$ or $D_5$).

Answer (score 2):

The statement holds when the orders of $a$ and $b$ are co-prime and $a$ is not the identity. You were almost there:

Proof by contraposition. Assume there is $x \in \left<b\right>a \cap \left<b\right>$. Then $x = b^n = b^m a$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, so $a = b^{n - m}$. But the order of $b^{n - m}$ divides the order of $b$, because $\langle b^{n - m} \rangle \subseteq \langle b \rangle$. Because of that, the orders of $a$ and $b^{n-m}$ are also coprime, even though they are the same element. Then $a$ has order $1$ and is the identity.